# How to accumulate a value in java?

Tags: java, class, constructor, instance, accumulator

Right now, I'm learning all about class, constructors and instances. I've made a small bit of code in java and I'm stuck with this particular code.

***MY CODE OUTPUT IS SUPPOSE TO BE LIKE THIS:

OUTPUT

Enter amount:500

Do you want to enter amount again?(y/n):y

Enter amount:45

Do you want to enter amount again?(y/n):n

TOTAL:545

***BUT INSTEAD MY OUTPUT IS LIKE THIS:

OUTPUT

Enter amount:500

Do you want to enter amount again?(y/n):y

Enter amount:45

Do you want to enter amount again?(y/n):n

TOTAL:45

***It is not adding the amount that I enter throughout the loop and instead, it is giving me the very last amount that I input.

Here is the first code:

```
public class Test {
private double money;

public Test(){

}

public void addPoints(double money1){
    money += money1;
}

public int getMoney(){
    return money;
}
```

}

and the second code is here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testBody {
   public static void main(String[]args){
    double cashMoney;
    String response = "";
    Scanner hold = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{


    System.out.print("Enter amount:");
    cashMoney = hold.nextDouble();
    Test cashPlus = new Test();
    cashPlus.addPoints(cashMoney);


    System.out.print("Do you want to enter amount again?(y/n):");
    response = hold.next();

    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){

        System.out.print("TOTAL: " + cashPlus.getMoney());
    }

    }while(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the `Test` instance before the loop instead of in each iteration.

```
Test cashPlus = new Test();
do {
    System.out.print("Enter amount:");
    cashMoney = hold.nextDouble();
    cashPlus.addPoints(cashMoney);
    System.out.print("Do you want to enter amount again?(y/n):");
    response = hold.next();

    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
        System.out.print("TOTAL: " + cashPlus.getMoney());
    }
} while(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

Each time you create a new Test instance, `cashMoney` is initialized to 0 (since each instance has its own value of that member). When you finally print `cashPlus.getMoney()`, you print the value of the last instance you created, to which you only added the final amount you entered.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `Test cashPlus = new Test();` you are creating a new Test object every time a value is entered. This effectively resets the already existing sum, because in the new class `Test.money` equals 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line being inside the do/while loop:

```
Test cashPlus = new Test();
```

The Test class object holds the variable money (which is initialized to 0) and you are creating a new instance of it with each iteration of the do/while loop, thus resetting cashPlus.money to 0.

Just move that line before of the do/while and you should be fine!

Answer (score 0):

In the loop , you are creating

```
Test cashPlus = new Test();
```

with this statement every time you are creating new object and adding sum to it. In all it is added to a new value as with new object it initialized to 0.

To avoid this instantiate the

```
Test cashPlus = new Test();
```

before starting the loop.

Answer (score -1):

**replace**

`private double money;`

**with**

`private static int money;`

Everytime you set the value, it becomes 0. To pertain the value make it a static variable.

Note that the return type of getMoney is `int` and the datatype of money is `double`. This has to be type-casted or changed to similar data-type.